# How to apply 80 character line width in Rmd files?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

With a quite large group, we have translated R4DS into spanish, and we all used different line widths.

I want to standardize this to 80 characters per line to avoid `lines    reading this  way`. In Atom this is just `ctrl + shift + q` but it breaks the code chunks.

Is there a way to break the lines just in text paragraphs from RStudio?

I don't want to hit enter ~20,000 times to convert this:

[image]

into this:

[image]